# How to find a triplet in an integer array

Tags: c#

I have an integer array . I want to find whether any triplet exists in the given array

```
int[] arr = [1,2,2,3,2,4];

public int FindTriplet(int[] arrayrecieve)
{
// TO return 1 ; // if the array has a triplet (foe example above array has 2,2,2)
```

}

else

return 0;

}

Comment: 3 nested loops.. ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Linq's `GroupBy()` and find all groups with a count of at least 3:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 6, 5, 4, 9};
var triplets = arr.GroupBy(x => x).Where(y => y.Count() >= 3).Select(z => z.First());
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", triplets)); // Prints 2, 4
```

This works as follows:

1. `GroupBy(x => x)` subdivides all the elements of the array into groups of the same number (i.e. all the 1's go in one group, all the 2's in another and so on).
2. `Where(y => y.Count() >= 3)` filters the groups such that only those with a count (i.e. number of items) of at least 3 are included.
3. `Select(z => z.First())` take each of those filtered groups and selects only the first element of each (note that each element in a group will of course be the same).

Note that you can also write the above initialisation of `triplets` like so:

```
var triplets = 
    from number in arr
    group number by number into grouped
    where grouped.Count() >= 3
    select grouped.First();
```

For your specific requirement of wanting to return 1 if there is at least one triplet, you would do this:

```
int result = triplets.Any() ? 1 : 0;
```

(Although I would have thought you'd want to return a bool rather than an int)

Also if you wanted to find groups with a count of exactly 3 instead, you'd just change the `Where()` to: `.Where(y => y.Count() == 3)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're returning 1 or 0 you should probably just return a bool unless you have a specific reason to require an int.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public bool hasTriplet(int[] values)
{
    foreach (int i in values)
    {
        if (values.Where(v => v == i).ToList().Count >= 3)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```